# Does puppet have an official module for Oracle Db operations

Tags: puppet

Is there an official puppetlab module for the Oracle database? (I found one for MySQL and Postgres)

Comment: if you can't find it in https://forge.puppetlabs.com, then the answer is NO. There are several not-puppetlabs oracle modules, you can still use them.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a PuppetLabs maintained module for OracleDB (as of when I'm writing this post, there may be in the future - [Here's a search to use to check](https://github.com/search?q=user%3Apuppetlabs%20oracle&type=Repositories))

But if you search on the [Forge](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/) as BMW suggested, there are a number of non-PuppetLabs maintained modules you could try:

- https://github.com/biemond/biemond-oradb
- https://github.com/hajee/oracle